# CLI active scan ZAP on DVWA - no vulns found

Tags: docker, authentication, zap

I'm running an authenticated scan with ZAP (docker form) on a VM, in Command Line but it doesn't found vulnerabilities. I'm doing this:
[scan steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URKxh.png)

First I make sure ZAP knows the URL with open-url, then I spider it and finally I launch the active scan, it seems to be good as there is no errors but in the report we have (only) this:
[XSS_r report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QHaJ.png)

So we should have here a red error about XSS but there's nothing. I get the same results dor the other pages.
Another question came in my mind, we can only spider or launch an active scan on one URL, how can we make a report with all the URLs of a website ? Instead of having one report for each page.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The ZAP Cli is a third party tool - you can use it if you want but its not supported by the ZAP Core Team.
The recommended automation options are given on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/
Try running the packaged full scan.

Comment: I had a look about it, I have the following error: _75235 [ZAP-ProxyThread-4] ERROR org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.ScriptBasedAuthenticationMethodType - Unable to find script while loading Script Based Authentication Method for name: authDvwa_
I don't see any option with which we can specify the authentication script (which is specified in the context file). Any idea about that ?
The script is from: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/details/setting-up-zap-to-test-dvwa/

Comment: I worked on this a bit more;  I have <name>authDvwa</name> in my context file (imported from GUI) and I added the authentication script (which is authDvwa.js) in _/home/zap/.ZAP/scripts/scripts/authentication/_ . I tried to launch the following command: _zap-full-scan.py -t http://192.168.56.108/dvwa/ -n authDvwa -U Administrator -r reportFullScan.html **-z "-config script.script.name="authDvwa.js" -config script.script.type=authentication -config script.script.enabled=true -config script.script.file="/zap/authDvwa.js""**_
_ But I still have "Unable to find script while loading Script..."

Comment: Are you sure the script is at "/zap/authDvwa.js" ? I suspect it wont be. You can start a bash shell in the container using the same docker command and double check. Wht docker command are you using?